Bathroom Plumbing Wet Vent Design
I'm adding a new bathroom to my home which includes a toilet, shower, and double vanity.  The 3" drain line will WYE into the main right before exiting the foundation (Not shown).  I have enough room for 1/4" slope (or more) on everything.  To minimize vent holes through the roof, I'd like to build a "wet vent" system I've only read about up till now.
If I tie the wet vent into the shower WYE, does that still act as a wet vent for the main toilet line?
Here is what my current plan looks like:

The toilet is about 21" from the foundation wall so I don't have a lot of space to branch out early.
Here is a top-down view

My city follows the state of Oregon plumbers code and does not have local requirements.

So, UPC 2021 (as adopted with amendments) is your state code, evidently.

@Ecnerwal - Looks like it.  The link I'm using says "Based on the 2021 UPC" under the title.  https://epubs.iapmo.org/2023/OPC/

Ugh. 908.2.1 appears to start right off with self-contradicting  language (Page 110 per the PDF, 85 per the document.) "The dry vent connection to the wet vent shall be an individual vent for the bidet, shower or bathtub. One or two vented lavatory(s) shall be permitted to serve as the wet vent for a bathroom group." Needs a word like "Or" "Alternatively" or some such on the start of the second sentence to actually be clear that either one is OK, after having started with that first sentence. Imprecise language leads to conflicts with inspectors...

I'm not a code expert but just curious if you cannot run a vent (or two) up the wall near the shower and toilet then over the ceiling to the existing one, so everything is dry vented and you have only one roof penetration?

@Ecnerwal what does "the dry vent connection" mean?  The dry vent will always be connected to something first, after which it's wet.   Does it mean you can use a double Y (like OP's) only if both things are lavs but otherwise you need staggered Ys?    Seems like  a lot of language to say that ... but I know I don't get it.

As I said, it's unclear as written, to me. I strongly suspect the OPs connection is fine, (certainly is under IPC) but the word choice, editing, etc. is so poor that it is, in fact, unclear as written.

Thanks for the comments.  I have a meeting setup with the inspector tomorrow and will report back on his interpretation for anyone interested.

My building inspector reviewed the plans and approved them.  He said it is indeed a horizontal wet vent all the way to the main line.  The only critique given was to make sure the horizontal 3" elbow on the toilet line after the wye is a long sweep.
